# Python singleton acting strange

Tags: python, python-3.x, singleton

I've found one of most popular approach to create singleton classes, using **_instance** and overriding **__new__** method. Here it is:

```
class Singleton:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance
```

But it acting weird when I try to use it this way:

```
class Child(Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = random.randint(10, 1000)
```

```
x = Child()
y = Child()
print(x.__dict__)        # {'a': 74}
print(y.__dict__)        # {'a': 74}  - not weird
print(Child().__dict__)  # {'a': 222} - weird (for me)
```

Can someone explain why it happens?

PS: I'm using python 3.10

Comment: Move `print(x.__dict__)` above `y = Child()` and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### An answer

In order to create an object, Python first calls `__new__` on its class, then calls `__init__` on the object.

When you "create" an instance of `Child`, Python will call `Singleton.__new__` and then `Child.__init__`. But `Singleton.__new__` always returns the same object, `_instance`, so `Child.__init__` will always re-initialise the same object.

`x` and `y` contain the same object, because all `Child`s are the same object. That's why `x.__dict__` and `y.__dict__` are the same. But when you call `Child` the third time, it reinitialises the object, changing its dict. `print(Child().__dict__)` gives a different value because it calls `Child` before printing.

It's not that the third call to `Child` produces a different object; rather that the object itself changes.

#### Some notes on singletons

You shouldn't use `__init__` if you're implementing a singleton in this way, because it will be called every time `Child` is called and reinitialise the object. If you need to initialise values of the singleton, you can do so in `__new__`, within the if statement, so that the initialisation is only done once.

Also consider why you need to create a subclass of a singleton. A singleton should only ever have one member, so if there are any instances of `Child`, it must be that all `Singleton`s are `Child`s, and so `Singleton` and `Child` might as well be merged into one class.